# How to get the size/length of ResultObject in Java?

Tags: java, collections

I have  ResultObject resultObject;

The resultObject.getResponseBody() is resulting as follows.

```
[ {  
      "id":"12",
      "age":12,
      "name":"abc"
   },
   {  
      "id":"13",
      "age":12,
      "name":"asd"
   },
   {  
      "id":"14",
      "age":12,
      "name":"qwe"
   },
]
```

I wanted to get the count of resultObject.getResponseBody() and to get the count resultObject.getResponseBody().length() and resultObject.getResponseBody().size() is not working.
Could someone help on this?

Comment: and what type is ResponseBody?

Comment: What's the differerence between length, count and size?

Comment: If you have access to the response header, you can read the Content-Length.

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you. You have dumped some JSON data, and one line of your code. How do you think that anybody would be able to help based on such input?

Comment: This is unanswerable at present - we don't know what type "ResultObject" is (that's not a standard JDK object), nor that returned by "getResponseBody()".

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the .getResponseBody() returns an Array of object of some kind, therefore you could try following:

```
    public int countElements(){
       int i = 0;
       while(resultObject.getResponseBody()[i] != null){
            counter ++;
       }
    }
```